# JPA во время сохранения Entity?

Tags: hibernate, spring-jpa, entity

С БД приходит дополнительная колонка (level) которой нет в самой таблице, она формируется путем Рекурсивного запроса.
Если я добавляю поле level в Entity, при добавлении или изменении строки в БД выходит ошибка что такой колонки в Таблице не существует.
Аннотация @Transient частично решает эту проблему,  поле level игнорируется в запросе, но при этом при получении данных с базы поле level всегда приходит  = null, а без Аннотация @Transient я получаю значение поля level, но сохранить или изменить данные не могу.
Есть ли способ получать данные вычисляемой БД колонки и при этом иметь возможность изменять и добавлять данные в БД  ?

```
Entity(name = "dict_category")
data class DictCategoryEntity (

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val id: Long?,

        @Column(name = "parent_id")
        val parent: Long?,


       
        val level: Long?,

        @Column(name = "code", unique = true)
        val code: String?,

        @Column(name = "name_ru", length = 5000)
        val name_ru: String?,

        @Column(name = "name_kz", length = 5000)
        val name_kz: String?,

        @Column(name = "name_en", length = 5000)
        val name_en: String?,

        @Column(name = "description", length = 5000)
        val description: String?,

        @Column(name = "icon", length = 5000)
        val icon: String?,

        @Column(name = "create_date")
        @CreationTimestamp
        var createDate: Date?,

        @Column(name = "update_date")
        @UpdateTimestamp
        var updateDate: Date?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вычисляемого поля используйте аннотацию `@Formula`:

```
@Formula("level")
private Long level;
```

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column dictcatego0_.level does not exist не работает, к сожалению

Comment: Пропустил, что это поле вычисляемое. Изменил ответ.

Comment: @Formula("level") используя данный вариант, приходит ошибка Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)" because "columnName" is null.

Comment: kz.csi.stat.csc.utils.CustomException: JSON_icategory